# E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting table * has no column named * after adding column into db Android Kotlin Java SQLite

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Hi i had problem adding data to allready created db after making few changes (adding columns)

**The fix for me was change name of the whole database ( name.db -> name1.db)**

Just hope this helps I wasted whole day trying almost everything

Answer (score 0):

**The fix for me was change name of the whole database ( name.db -> name1.db)**